# how to use bootstrap icons only?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I have a project with its own css files.

Now I want to use some icons. Bootstrap icon is a good choice. But, I only need icons. I don't need anything else. I go to [Customize Page](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)  to customize my downloading. I select only glyphicons and leave the other files. But when I import it into my project, it comes with all css, which makes my UI a mess.

So what should I do if I only want to use the icons?

Comment: Why don't you use FontAwesome? http://fontawesome.io/

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested above you can use font awesome and have access to all of FA icons without including the bootstrap styling just include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

to create an icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
```

Comment: Font awesome is AWESOME, but...

1. It has bad usability - This can be solved by using SVG icons instead and use them as foreground images with proper alt and title.
2. It is too large - You normally need to download all icons at once. To prevent this, you can subset your icon font. Subsetting can be done using a service like http://fontello.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Bootstrap icon you just have to use CDN in your Html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Use icon tag and write the icon name, you can get amazing bootstrap icons on https://icons.getbootstrap.com/

```
<i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i>
```

You can easily do the styling according to your UI

```
<i class="bi bi-trash3-fill" style="font-size:48px;color:red;"></i>
```

It needs some steps and your UI will look more attractive